# Does every series of first moves have an opening name?

Tags: opening

Recently, I just noticed how many openings there are. This gave me a question. Does every set of first legal moves have an "opening" name. I am referring more than just reasonable moves; all legal moves are included.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every first move by White has a name. There does not appear to be a name for every *set* of first moves, however. I could find no name for `1. a3 f6`, for example. But there *is* a name for every Black move after `1. e4`.

Comment: is there a name for e4 b5?

Comment: Lichess says it's the O'Neill Gambit.

Comment: exactly! i noticed that too but had some doubts so i decided to ask [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/41905/is-there-a-name-for-the-opening-moves-1-e4-b5) since lichess uses wikibooks to show openings on the left panel

Answer (score 9):

It's important to realize that opening names *aren't official*. There are lots of opening names that e.g. someone invented for their website or database program, but that nobody in the chess world who doesn't use that program recognizes. The set of widely recognized names is much smaller.

E.g. I have no doubt that 1.h3 has been given names. I also believe that if you went to a huge tournament with lots of GMs present and asked everyone for the name of that move, *nobody* will offer one. A name for an opening isn't much use if it can't be used to refer to those moves when talking to chess players.

Computers will tell you that 1.Nf3 is the "Zukertort Opening". But I've only ever heard chess players refer to it as "Nf3", and that's what many opening books do too (like the *1.Nf3 -- Opening for White According to Kramnik* series). *Fundamental Chess Openings* calls 1.Nf3 the "Reti Opening", but others reserve that name only for 1.Nf3 d5 2.c4. And so on.

So yes, lists of opening names can get very long, but that doesn't necessarily mean very much. Your question ("does every series of first moves have a name") should mention which particular list of opening names you're talking about.