# is there a name for the opening moves 1. e4 b5?

Tags: opening, terminology, gambits, 1.e4, eco

While this is a terrible opening which gives up a pawn for nothing I would like to know if it has a name.

Wikibooks state that it is called [O'Neill Gambit](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Chess_Opening_Theory/1._e4/1...b5) but its citations lead nowhere. The only citation it has is a [365chess page](https://www.365chess.com/opening.php?m=3&n=1037&ms=e4.b5&ns=3.1037) which just says `B00: King's Pawn Opening`

Is there a reliable source which verifies this? Any idea how it got the name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no name in Oxford Companion to Chess, so there was probably no name in general usage up to 1990 or so. It would be classified as a 'Royal Opening' by 1. e4.

There may be later names, but I know of no equally authoritative source. There's a certain cachet in opening names, so unless there are multiple sightings of a name, preferably independent, any finds should be taken with a grain of salt. (I find it unlikely that anyone would be in need of a name of this opening.) Of course, additional moves may produce a position that can also be reached in another opening, in which case its name may be more appropriate.

As the purpose of using a name presumably is telling someone what the opening is ... but unless the name is already accepted and well-known it obviously doesn't work.  If there is a useful ECO code, it may be better than names. In this case, it would be a B00 opening, but I have to leave any further refinements to someone with an up-to-date ECO code table.

Comment: I have ECO B from 1984, and Eric Schiller's Unorthodox Chess Openings and neither include 1. e4 b5.